# How to access docker container from another machine?

Tags: docker, networking

I need to access docker containers from another machine and every container use the same port. 
Example:
[image: a busy cat]

How can i do that. I tried vpn server but i didnt get success

Comment: You could use SSH between ubuntu machines, then docker cli.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408764/how-to-connect-directly-to-a-remote-docker-container-with-ssh

Answer (score 0):

when you run the container, you must expose an port, and that port can't be the same while the containers are in the same machine.